# How can i populate collections in Firestore Emulator?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I have a function which returns a list of objects, I need some way so that i can populate this data in local firestore emulator and not in actual cloud firestore instance.
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Firestore emulator can [import data on startup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#import_and_export_data) by starting it with:

```
firebase emulators:start --import=./dir
```

The data to be imported has to be in a proprietary format though, so you'll want to convert your data into that format by:

1. Writing it to the Firestore emulator using the regular Firestore API.
2. Export the data to the import/export format by running `firebase emulators:export ./dir`.
3. And **then** import the data into the emulator on startup as shown above.